# date/times incorrectly formatting

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have a macro which is trying to combine a date field with a time field:
        `Sheets(2).Cells(t, 3).Value = Cells(t, 2).Text & " " & Cells(t, 3).Text`

however when it reaches the 1st of the next month it switches the date and time columns. e.g. It should be 01-09-2017 but it goes as 09-01-2017.

I have tried reformatting dates using lines like this:
        `Sheets(2).Range("B6:B" & lastRowSheetTwo).ClearFormats '= "dd-mmm-yyyy"`
however they all have the same problem.

I have tried removing all formatting from the dates/times and reformatting them after they have been combined however once the date and time have been deformatted excel doesnt seem to know how to reformat them.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It would be better to do `Cells(t, 2).Value + Cells(t, 3).Value` then format as you wish.  VBA is very US-EN centric and it does the dates in that format.  So use the numbers values instead.

Comment: Would you mind explaining the difference between "value + value" and "value & " " & value" ?

Comment: Yes Excel does dates as number of days since 1/1/1900 and time as a decimal part of a day.  So today noon would be `43018.5` so if you add the two values in one you would have `43018` formatted as a date and the other `0.5` as a time.  You add the two together to get a cell with both date and time.  The other concatenates the values.  so you would end up with `"43018 .5"` as text instead of `43018.5` which excel would see as `10/10/2018 12:00:00` if formatted correctly.  The problem with `.Text & " "  & .Text` is that VBA will see `9/1/2018` as sept 1st not jan 9th.

Comment: I see, thank you. So it's better to use the addition for numbers and the && signs for strings?

Comment: Yes, And remember when working with dates in excel they are numbers and not text strings.  The numbers just happen to be formatted in a different form.

Comment: and is there a way to create a space between the two values? currently the cell contents looks like this: 31-Aug-1712:09:32 I tried reformatting, with `Sheets(2).Range("C6:C" & lastRowSheetOne).NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM"` however it doesn't add the space. Also would you mind adding your solution as an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: Fix your formatting to put the space.

Comment: I tried reformatting, with `Sheets(2).Range("C6:C" & lastRowSheetOne).NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM" `however it doesn't add the space. Also would you mind adding your solution as an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: If that did not change it then your dates and times are text not true dates and times and the `+` is acting like `&`.  So my answer will not work.  You need to first change the values to true date/times.

Comment: They should be, I have these lines before the lines that combine the two:     `Sheets(2).Range("B6:B" & lastRowSheetTwo).NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yyyy"        Sheets(2).Range("C6:C" & lastRowSheetTwo).NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss AM/PM"`

Comment: Hi sorry, I realized what I was doing wrong, I still had the text keywords instead of value. It works now

Answer (score 0):

Use `.Text` on both sides, as in

```
Sheets(2).Cells(t, 3).Text= Cells(t, 2).Text & " " & Cells(t, 3).Text
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I have tried this, however excel doesn't let you set the text property of a cell, only the value. This will result in an error